# Why are interfaces subtypes of Object in Java?

Tags: java, interface, language-design, subtyping

Why are interfaces with no super interface subtypes of Object in Java? 
What I am asking about here is why was this design choice taken by the language creators i.e. what is the practical purpose of this subtyping?

Comment: It would clarify this question, if you could provide a piece of Java code which compares the types. You know, to ask "why does this expression evaluate to true?" kind of question.

Comment: @hyde I know this is a super late reply and I can't exactly remember why I didn't reply in May 2019 (although I do remember being extremely busy at the time finishing my post-graduate diploma and preparing to start looking for my first job as a junior SWE) so my sincere apologies for that. However, I think this question as a theoretical question about programming language design is clear and on-topic on SO without the Java code and it indeed got good answers. I also think it proved to be a somewhat popular and hence common question with ~1k views, closing it was not a correct decision IMHO.

Comment: Language design questions are, in general, a better fit for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the practical purpose of this subtyping?

The practical purpose is that you can call [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#method.summary) methods using a variable whose type is an interface, most commonly `toString()`, `equals()`, and `hashCode()`.

In order for a variable of an interface type to have a non-null value, an object instance must be assigned to it. Since all objects extends `Object`, it's guaranteed that any object implementing the interface also extends `Object`.

E.g. [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface, but you can call `myList.toString()` even though `toString()` is not defined for that interface.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are just a "specification" for their subclasses. They usually don't provide any implementeation. So essentially an interface is the most abstract way an object can be seen in Java. However, Java 8 and above provide `default` and `static` methods with implementation so this makes interfaces even more similar to abstract classes. 
Since every object inherits from Object class, and since interfaces are just an abstract representation of an object, they too need to inherit from an Object.

**Note that every class, abstract class and interface that does not explicitly specify their super class, gets assigned Object class as their direct super class at compile time.**

This is because Object class already provides some methods that all objects need to implement (e.g. `equals()`, `toString()`,...). Especially usefuly methods are `hashCode()` which is used in various hashtables, or `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` which are used when writing multithreaded programs. Because of inheritance you will almost never need to call these methods explicitly, however, if classes did not inherit from Object you would need to write all of these by yourself for every class. Object class therefore reduces programming effort to some extent.

Additionally, this also enables making an argument of type "any", when the value is unknown.

```
void printObject(Object any) {
    System.out.println("Printing object of type: " + any.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(any); // toString called "implicitly"
}
```

Do try to avoid this kind of code if possible.